# Tean Services Build Agent and System.Io.Compression

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

We have a setup with MS Team Services where we have some local build agents. Recently we had some issues with errors about a not found system.io.compression. At the same time we could use hosted agents, but want to have the local running again. On one machine we managed to install a new agent that worked, but on another we get an error about system.io.compression when we try to install the agent. I'm not sure why this is suddenly an issue, maybe som gac mess up or other thing we need to clean up. the machines running the agents all have the latest Visual Studio 2017 installed

Comment: A fresh installation/repair of .net 4.6.2 seems to fix the issue

Comment: Could you please post it as the answer for this issue and mark it.